# Computer won't boot with Intel 10Gb NIC installed

Tags: boot, motherboard, network-adapter

I'm attempting to install an Intel X520-DA2 10Gb converged network adapter in my computer and the machine will not boot while the card is installed. The computer powers on, but the BIOS splash screen never appears and the boot process never begins. The motherboard error code sits stuck at 55 ("memory not installed") during this time. As soon as I remove the network card, the computer returns to booting normally and everything works fine.

I was first experiencing this problem on an MSI Z97 GAMING 5, so I called MSI tech support and they told me to update to the latest beta BIOS and call back if that doesn't solve the issue. So, I updated the BIOS and it completely bricked the motherboard. >_< Frustrated and not wanting to wait 3 weeks for an RMA, I went to the store and bought another Z97 motherboard: the ASUS Maximus VII Hero. I figured the problem was exclusive to the MSI GAMING 5. Nope, the exact same situation is now occurring on the ASUS motherboard. I have tested it in both available PCI-E slots.

The obvious answer would be that the network card is bad, but it works perfectly fine when I put it in my Supermicro-based server machine. I have also tried a different network card (Mellanox Infiniband card) in both the MSI and ASUS boards and it works fine. At this point I can't even guess what the issue is. Is it possible for this network card to just be outright incompatible with the Z97 chipset? Is there perhaps some backwards compatibility setting in the BIOS that I'm missing?

If it helps, I have an i7-4790K, 32 GB of g.skill DDR3 memory, an 850 watt power supply, and an GTX 980 Ti video card in the top PCI-E slot.

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Comment: The easy "answer" is that it's a server-grade card and requires a server-grade chipset.  The Z97 in any form is not on the [compatibility list for that adapter](http://ark.intel.com/products/39776/Intel-Ethernet-Converged-Network-Adapter-X520-DA2#@compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with ASRock x790m-itx and Intel 550 adapter. A bios update to the most recent version fixed the issue. No server grade hardware required and x790 chipset works fine with the Intel 550 10GB adapter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).